# php xml SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml

```
<Placemark id="p1"></Placemark>
<Placemark id="p2"></Placemark>
<Placemark id="p3"></Placemark>
<Placemark id="p4"></Placemark>
```

hi,im using SimpleXMLElement in my php,
my question is,how do i get placemark id 3?
is that something like this ?

```
$page = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($request_url));
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($page);
$xml->Response->Placemark['id=p3']->AddressDetails->Country->CountryName;
```

thanks

Comment: you have id=3 in your PHP code, but id="p3" in your XML. I don't know if this is causing you problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml->xpath("Placemark[@id='p3']")->AddressDetails->Country->CountryName;
```

XPath is your friend :-)